# Spring security OAuth2 client Authenticate using client_secret_jwt: how to setRequestEntityConverter?

Tags: spring-security

When testing a OAuth2 client using client_secret_jwt  I get an error with a prompt about using `setRequestEntityConverter`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class supports `client_secret_basic`, `client_secret_post`, and `none` by default. Client [****abc****] is using [client_secret_jwt] instead. Please use a supported client authentication method, or use `setRequestEntityConverter` to supply an instance that supports [client_secret_jwt].
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:129) ~[spring-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.ClientAuthenticationMethodValidatingRequestEntityConverter.convert(ClientAuthenticationMethodValidatingRequestEntityConverter.java:42) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
```

I try to follow the Spring Security guide:
[Authenticate using client_secret_jwt](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/client-authentication.html#_authenticate_using_client_secret_jwt)
and creating a OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient bean that "*setRequestEntityConverter*"

```
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient() {

        OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequestEntityConverter requestEntityConverter =
                new OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequestEntityConverter();
        requestEntityConverter.addParametersConverter(
                new NimbusJwtClientAuthenticationParametersConverter<>(jwkResolver));

        DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient tokenResponseClient =
                new DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
        tokenResponseClient.setRequestEntityConverter(requestEntityConverter);

        return tokenResponseClient;
    }
```

And I also added OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager :

```
    @Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository,
        OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient) {

    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                    .clientCredentials(builder ->
                            builder.accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient
                            )
                    )
                    .build();

    DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    return authorizedClientManager;
}
```

What am I missing?
do I need to add more beans, or something to the SecurityFilterChain bean? or the ClientRegistration?

versions:
spring-boot-starter-parent 3.2.0 that has
spring-security 6.2.0

Answer (score 0):

For me I found if I set client-authentication-method in application configuration to client_secret_basic or client_secret_post, I believe it will work for you.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          spotify-client:
            client-authentication-method: client_secret_post
```