Spring boot 2.x.x migration to 3.2.4 problem with OAuth2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class supports `client_secret_basic`, `client_secret_post`, and `none` by default. Client [onboarding_service] is using [post] instead. Please use a supported client authentication method, or use `setRequestEntityConverter` to supply an instance that supports [post].
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:129) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOnCallable] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeOn(Mono.java:4618)
    org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.authorizeClient(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.java:487)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *______Mono.subscribeOn ⇢ at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.authorizeClient(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.java:487)
    *__________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.lambda$filter$14(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.java:383)
    *____________Mono.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.filter(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.java:380)
    *____Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.filter(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.java:379)
    |_             Mono.map ⇢ at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.filter(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.java:386)
    |_         Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.filter(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.java:387)
    |_   Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.filter(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.java:388)
    |_           checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET https://onboarding-api.account- [DefaultWebClient]
    |_   Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$11(DefaultWebClient.java:461)
    |_        Mono.doOnNext ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$11(DefaultWebClient.java:467)
    |_       Mono.doOnError ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$11(DefaultWebClient.java:468)
    |_       Mono.doFinally ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$11(DefaultWebClient.java:469)
    |_    Mono.contextWrite ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$11(DefaultWebClient.java:475)
    *__Mono.deferContextual ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultWebClient.java:443)
    |_         Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.bodyToMono(DefaultWebClient.java:572)


Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78218583/11478354

adding that in application.properties but not got same issue.

What did you add in the application.properties?

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.uid.client-authentication-method=client_secret_basic

seems you are using post, not client_secret_basic
did you try  spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.uid.client-authentication-method=post ?
